# I want when I fill my database ,if a value is REPETITIOUS ,then appeared error

Tags: c#, database

I use this code till I see data in my database and edit,delet and insert data in that . but I want when I insert data to database , that is not REPETITIOUS , and if that is REPETITIOUS show me a message box about it.

Code :

```
private void btnok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id = idTextBox.Text.ToString();
        string name = nameTextBox.Text.ToString();
        string family = familyTextBox.Text.ToString();
        table1BindingSource.EndEdit();
        table1TableAdapter.Update(database1DataSet.Table1);

    }

    private void butins_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        table1BindingSource.AddNew();
    }

    private void butdelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        table1BindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
        table1TableAdapter.Update(database1DataSet.Table1);
    }

    private void butedit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        table1BindingSource.EndEdit();
        table1TableAdapter.Update(database1DataSet.Table1);
    }
```

I write this Query,but I dont know , how can I use that?
I write that in "Database1DataSet.xsd" , and appeared fillby() and gatedataby() in Tableadapter.

query :

```
SELECT     id, name, family
FROM         Table1
WHERE     (id = @id) AND (name = @name) AND (family = @family)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that you follow Marc's answer.

The exception you'll catch is a SqlException with error number 2601, it may be something like this:

```
catch(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException lExSql)
{
    if(lExSql.Number == 2601)
        return Result.Duplicate;
    else
        return Result.Failure;
}
catch
{
    return Result.Failure;
}
```

Also a side note: there's no need to call TextBox.Text.ToString(), because the Text property is a String itself.

Comment: if I put UNIQUE constraint to columns ,can I write nember or string or any type of data in a field

Comment: Yes you can, as long as this data don't make a duplicate with existing data in the database

Comment: do you meaning of UNIQUE ,is set uniqueiclentifier type for a feild ?

Comment: No, UNIQUE is a constraint implemented as an index, it has nothing to do with the data type of the column(s) it's applied to.
While uniqueidentifier, is a 128 GUID type.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could put a UNIQUE constraint spanning the interesting columns (presumably `[id]`, `[name]` and `[family]`) in the database... that will prevent duplicates pretty well (by raising an exception that you can catch and message box appropriately).

The other approach is to check for existing values first - but unless you use something like serializable isolation-level you still have a race condition.

Comment: if I put UNIQUE constraint to columns ,can I write nember or string or any type of data in a field ?

Comment: I don't quite follow... can you clarify?

Comment: do you meaning of UNIQUE ,is set uniqueiclentifier type for a feild ?